# what does this do

Tags: python

This is a question Im trying to figure out for a job pre-interview questioniar.  and i dont know python that well so im struggling with this problem.

the real questions for the job are big-o performance and making it better but i can do that i just need to understand this code

**question A**: in is_bar they compare the iterator to the array (if i == b).  is this the equivalent of (if i == b.length)?

**question B**: 
so following the flow of the function and assuming the above and (a = [1,2,3] b=[3,4,5]) is true the first comparison is comparing two iterators????

so it would be:

1. is_bar(b, 0)
2. for i in b   (says a but its b from above)
3. if 0 == 0
4. so it evaluates to true and does c.append(0)
5. does this 3 more times and since its comparing iterators it would append 1,2 than unique (c)
   6.which makes a new array the same size as c and makes every values = 1

but that wouldnt make sense.  Appearently there is somthing im missing because a function that takes 2 arrays, then creates an array of equal size of the second array and makes all values = 1 would be stupid.

**question C**: what does b.keys() return exactly  (i looked up the function but it says "list of all the keys used" but that doesnt make sense since it is a one-dimension array)

```
 def foo(a, b):
         """ a and b are both lists """
         c = []
         for i in a:
             if is_bar(b, i):
                 c.append(i)
         return unique(c)

      def is_bar(a, b):
         for i in a:
             if i == b:
                 return True
         return False

      def unique(arr):
         b = {}
         for i in arr:
             b[i] = 1

         return b.keys()
```

Comment: I guess the principle here is that, if it is a question for an interview, they are interested in discovering your knowledge, analytical skills and programming ability - not the collective ability of Stackover flow users.

Comment: Learn python if you want a job doing python.

Comment: its not a python job, its an entry level java position. they know my skill are in java this is just a basic questioniar. i have done all the other three questions no problem (in java).  i just dont understand the code im not asking for the answer.  asking for the answer would be asking for the big-0 performance of the code and a better solution.

Comment: The name `b` is used in three different namespaces here, so has three different meanings. `keys` is called on it when it refers to a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A:** No. It compares each element of `a` to `b`. So if `b` is an element of `a` it returns `True`.

**B:** Change based on the above.

**C:** `b` is not an array. It's a dictionary (the `b = {}`).

Comment: A: i wish i could see how/where its doing that (not that im arguing i just dont see it, but this is what it has to be) i figured it was a union.   what would b.keys() return then, all values in the b array?  which would be all the unique entries of a and b combined

Comment: "i wish i could see how/where its doing that": `for i in a` (see [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)). "what would `b.keys()` return then, all values in the `b` array? which would be all the unique entries of a and b combined": yes.

Comment: thank you for that link.  wow thats different then all the languages ive seen.  this was why i didnt understand the code.  i thought "i" was an iterator

Comment: This construct is very popular with scripting languages and dynamically typed languages (sometimes called a `foreach` loop). [Java has it too](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) since 1.5

Answer (score 1):

the function can be simplified to:

```
def foo(a, b):
    """ a and b are both lists """
    return list(set(a)&set(b))
```

Comment: thank you but i didnt want this answer, although it is the answer.  i really am just trying to understand the code.  but thank you

Comment: and although im waiting for a response i dont think there are duplicate entries in the array, which this would do.

Comment: i was slightly more confident about my understanding than i should have been but that error has been corrected. the function indeed computes the intersection of two sets as shown by `assert foo([1,2],[2,3]) == [2]`